# Loadrunner - JMS - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: web-services, jms, loadrunner

I have sample Queue hosted in my local machine and I would like to send text messages to the Queue using load runner (Web Services Protocol)

`jms_send_message_queue("Msg1", "Sample Message from Loadrunner", "Queue1");`

When I execute above code getting below error message:

```
Action.c(4): jms_print_general_property - JVM_Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\LoadRunner\bin\..\lib\openjdk32\jre\
Action.c(4): jms_print_general_property - JMS_impl_classpath = %CLASSPATH%
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - JNDI_InitialContextFactory = org.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - JNDI_provider_URL = http://localhost:8161/
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - ConnectionFactory = ConnectionFactory
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - connections_per_process = 1
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - msg_timeout = 1
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - user_define_timeout = 20
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - SecurityPrincipal = admin
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - SecurityCredentials = admin
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - SetCorbaOrb = 
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - auto_generate_selector = 0
Action.c(4): jms_set_general_property called - EnableTibcoSslJndiLookup = 
Action.c(4): java.naming.provider.url = http://localhost:8161/
Action.c(4): java.naming.factory.initial = org.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
Action.c(4): java.naming.security.principal=admin
Action.c(4): java.naming.security.credentials=admin
Action.c(4): Error: Failed to send message This message sent from Loadrunner tool to Queue1 due to the following exception : javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory]
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:719)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at com.mercury.ws.jms.ConnectionManagerImpl.initialize(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:98)
    at com.mercury.ws.jms.JMSSupportImpl.initialize(JMSSupportImpl.java:28)
    at com.mercury.ws.jms.JMSBridge.init_jms(JMSBridge.java:154)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
    at java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.loadClass(VersionHelper.java:107)
    at java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.loadClass(VersionHelper.java:82)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:716)
    ... 6 more
Action.c(4): Error: JMS call execution failed
```

I tried adding **activemq-all-5.15.0.jar** file to JVM Path given below still same issue exists.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\LoadRunner\bin\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\LoadRunner\lib\openjdk32\jre\
```

Can you please help me with below questions:

1. From  where Loadrunner picked the JVM_Path? I don't see this path in my environment variables also.
2. What is the default classpath?
3. Are there any other jar files I need to include in JVM_Path in order overcome `ClassNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue. It is generally due to missing jars. Now you want to run a Messaging service so I believe some jars are missing, which you need to update in runtimesetting, in run time settings you should see something called classpath.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure which version of Load Runner do you have, but if it is the one I guess, then there is a Java delivered with the product, which is loaded by default in this use-case. If you want to use your own java, you can do it in the Runtime Settings dialogue -> JMS -> Advanced, by enabling the "Use JVM at this JRE location" and providing your JRE folder with full path.
2. The default classpath is the one is set in the %CLASSPATH% env variable, and some additional jars that Load Runner adds to it for the support. In the same runtime setting location, you can find the "Classpath" field, where you can add additional jars to the classpath. In this page you can also add additional parameters to the JVM, and configure your messaging service.
3. You need to add to the classpath all your jar files that you are referencing in the script.